# How to convert hair particles

Tags: particles

I have simple sphere and added some hair particles. I want to export it to obj file and i have converted the hair particles in modifier tab. And exported but i did not get the hair particles just normal sphere. 
How can i convert the hair particles.

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When you convert hair particles you get vertices connected by edges. Most programs will only draw faces so you won't see the hair outside of blender unless you create some geometry that can be drawn.

1. Convert the hair particles to mesh.

[image: convert particles]

2. Convert the hair particle mesh to a curve. <kbd>⎇ Alt</kbd><kbd>C</kbd>-> Curve from Mesh/Text

[image: make it a curve]

3. Add a bevel to the curve - effectively turn each strand into a tube. For the fill option, front and back will give a quarter tube, half a half tube and full will fully enclose it. The depth setting determines how big the tube is while the resolution will subdivide the tube to give a more rounded result, a resolution of zero will give a four sided tube with fill set to full. You can use the extrude value to give them an oval shape. Note that extra resolution increases the geometry to export but would provide little variation to the visual result of the small hair mesh.

[image: bevel it]

4. Convert to mesh. <kbd>⎇ Alt</kbd><kbd>C</kbd>->Mesh from Curve.

[image: convert to mesh]

5. Export.

Answer (score 0):

Select the object, then go to **Object Modifers** and click `Convert` in the Particle System menu.

[image]

This gives an extra mesh separate from the object, so you can remove the particle system from the object and join the objects together by selecting the hair and the object together (ensure object is active) and pressing <kbd>Ctrl+J</kbd>.

To give hair faces, set pivot point to 3D Cursor, and place the cursor in the center of the sphere and hair (if sphere and hair are in center, then just use `Cursor to Center` with <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>.)

[image]
[image]

Then enter edit mode **on the hairs**, and select all. Press <kbd>E</kbd> to extrude, then RMB. Then press <kbd>R</kbd> then <kbd>Z</kbd> to rotate on the Z Axis. Move the mouse to give thickness, then LMB to confirm.

Comment: thanks for u replying the problem im getting i have converted as i have mention in my question and with ur reference i have join with ctrl+j but when i import in keyshot i get only a normal sphere and no hair particles any solution

Comment: That's because it is simply a line of vertices. Blender's renders those hairs to they appear. You would have to extrude each of the hairs so it has faces for it appear.

Comment: can u plz clear the point (extrude each of hairs so it has faces) in detail the steps by step. thanks

Comment: I edited the post