# How to export hair particles to FBX, OBJ, GLB formats?

Tags: mesh, particles, export, hair, particle-edit-mode

I have a seal and applied some hair particles on it, but when I export the model the hair particles does not appear with it. I tried converting the hair particles into mesh but still does not work.

I tried exactly the methods mention here including the convert part and the extruding part  in [How to convert hair particles](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/70373/how-to-convert-hair-particles), but still when exporting it to FBX I see no hairs.

What am I doing wrong ?

[image: The model with hair particles in Blender]

[image: Up close picture with hair particles in Blender]

[image: Converting into mesh]

[image: After conversion]

[image: After exporting into FBX]

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/57531/fbx-export-why-there-are-no-materials-or-textures